# Get a return from nested function

Tags: javascript, function, meteor

I try to check (in a helper of a template) if an image exists - by an given url.

If the file exists, I want to set the spacebar to this url. 
If it doesn't exsist, another url should be returned.

My problem is to get the return out of the onload-/onerror-function:

```
Template.backgroundImage.helpers({
    image: function() {
        var url = '/background/'+file+'.jpg';

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() { return url; }
        img.onerror = function() { return '/background/image.jpg'; }
        img.src = url;
    }
});

<template name="backgroundImage">
    <img src="{{image}}">
</template>
```

Comment: Use `Session` to set the `image` path

Comment: @Tushar: perfect. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Promise:

```
Template.backgroundImage.helpers({
  image: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var img = new Image();
      var url = '/background/' + file + '.jpg';
      img.addEventListener('load', function() { resolve(url); });
      img.addEventListener('error', function() { resolve('/background/image.jpg'); });
      img.src = url;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Do meteor templates support promises returned from helpers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Template onRendered callback to update your image SRC on error :

```
Template.backgroundImage.helpers({
    image: function() {
        return '/background/'+file+'.jpg';
    }
});

Template.backgroundImage.onRendered(function(){
    var $img = this.$('img'); //Whatever your selector is, not sure if this.$ works in onRendered though

    // "one" makes sure event is only fired once, see below
    $img.one("error", function() {
     $img.attr('src','/background/image.jpg')
    });

    // If image was loaded, reload it
    // This is usually used to check if images were loaded from cache
    // but as you only want to track errors, it's probably unnecessary 
    if($img.get().complete) {
        $img.load();
    }
})
```